# Dynamically set background-color on html tag

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, iron-router

I need to dynamically set the background-color in the html tag.

```
<html style="background-color:{{ backColor }};">
```

How is this done in Meteor?

Comment: You mean `document.body.className="otherclass"` - did you mean retroactively?

Comment: and the question is.. 'can you do this for me?'

Comment: Please edit to reread yourself, explain what issue you are facing, ask a question. Right now I can barely understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple. Just added the style for `body` to the top of the template. Doesn't seem to be best practice, but it works on Chrome and Safari.

This also seems to work for the `html`tag.

```
<template name="spriteBox">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: {{ backColor }}
        }
    </style>
    <!-- rest of content -->
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem , When you resize ur window , you see white space in the bottom of the page ? If so removing height:100% in ur css will help you.

```
.contentbackground{width:100%;height:100%}
```

Change the above in ur stylesheet to

```
.contentbackground{width:100%;}
```

Comment: Where is the jQuery tag?

Comment: @mplungjan added for pure js

Comment: Thanks @Vishnu – but removing the height for `.contentbackground` actually makes things worse as the background will not cover the full height – even if I don't scroll.